# Creating a Search Folder and access to ReplyRecipients

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-redemption

I am trying to create a Search Folder in Outlook-2010 representing all MailItems concerning a particular email address.

I.e. the MailItems where the email address is set as a SenderEmailAddress or a Sender or one of the Recipients or one of the ReplyRecipients.

As far as I know I can't do this using the Application.AdavancedSearch method and DASL filter because there's no access to Recipients or ReplyRecipients.

I tried to set the restriction using Redemption Searches object:

```
Set Store = RDSessoin.Stores.DefaultStore
Set Searches = Store.Searches
Set Folder = Store.IPMRootFolder

Addr = "123@example.com" 'the email being searched

SQL = "(SenderEmailAddress LIKE '%" & Addr & "%') OR " & _
        "(Recipients LIKE '%" & Addr & "%')"

Set NewSearch = Searches.AddCustom(Addr, strSQL, Folder)
```

It works but it doesn't include ReplyRecipients and Sender conditions.

When I try to add them to the restriction

```
SQL = "(SenderEmailAddress LIKE '%" & Addr & "%') OR " & _
        "(Recipients LIKE '%" & Addr & "%') OR " & _
        "(ReplyRecipients LIKE '%" & Addr & "%') OR " & _
        "(Sender LIKE '%" & Addr & "%')"
```

the error "unknown property names" occurs.

What would the correct restriction syntax be and are there any other ways to create such a Search Folder?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `ReplyRecipients` since it is a binary property containing entry ids (which is not of much use), but you can use `ReplyRecipientNames` instead.

Comment: but displayed names and email-addresses aren't generally the same...

Comment: Yes, but that is the best you can do. The email address (if it is a one-off SMTP entry id)  is only available inside the binary property that holds the entry ids.

Comment: So there's absolutely no way to create the Search Folder I want in Outlook?

Comment: Correct. You won't be able to search on ReplyRecipients